# php 5.2.5 on Centos 5.4

Tags: php, drupal-7, centos

My client is using Centos 5.4 which has PHP 5.2.4.
We wish to use Drupal 7 for one of his site, however Drupal 7 needs PHP 5.2.5.

I tried to update the php version in Centos using yum but I get something like:
No Packages marked for Update

Is there anything I can do to get PHP updated to the proper version?

Thanks

Hugo

Comment: PHP 5.2.x is outdated and EOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

php 5.2 is outdated. if you need newer version of php following this code:

```
yum install php53
```

or compile from source

Answer (score 0):

You can download a source package [Here](http://in.php.net/releases/index.php) and compile PHP 5.2.5 on your machine.